# Ajax serialize() doesn't include data from dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascriptserializer

I have a form and I add divs here dynamically using `append()`. It is successful in creating the divs, and that divs have input fields inside. But the problem is, after serializing the the data from the form, it doesnt include the data from the dynamically created divs.

This is my `createDiv` function:

```
function createDiv() {
    var count = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $('#userQues').append("<div class='col-md-4'> <div class='form-group'> " +
            "<label class='control-label' for ='data[" + i + "][questiona]'> Question A </label>" +
            "<input id='data[" + i + "][questiona]' name='data[" + i + "][questiona]' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/>" +
            "</div> </div>");
    }
};
```

Is there a problem in creating my div? Why does serialize doesnt include the data from my created div?

Thanks in advance!

Here is where is serialize the data. When the form is submitted:

```
$('#explorer_form').submit(function(e){
  var serializedData = $('#explorer_form').serialize();
  alert(serializedData);

  $.ajax({
    url : url + api,
    type : method,
    data : serializedData,
    success : function(response){
        $('#response').val(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
  e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

And the form:

```
<form id='explorer_form'>
    <input id='uname' name='uname' type='text'/>
    <div id='userQues'></div>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</submit>
</form>
```

And now, the alerted data is only the data from the input 'uname' only. It doesn't serialize the data from the created div.

Comment: How/when do you call the serialize? Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I can not see the point where you do serialize. Also it would be smart to do a fiidle or pen because its more fun to the folks who like to help you :)

Comment: Use hidden field for this <div id='userQues'></div> not div

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your userQues is a form and that you do the serialize AFTER you added the inputs. Your code works, here: http://jsfiddle.net/9v3khbts/

HTML

```
<form id="userQues">
</form>

<button id="doSer">Serialize</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function createDiv() {
    var count = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $('#userQues').append("<div class='col-md-4'> <div class='form-group'> " +
            "<label class='control-label' for ='data[" + i + "][questiona]'> Question A </label>" +
            "<input id='data[" + i + "][questiona]' name='data[" + i + "][questiona]' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/>" +
            "</div> </div>");
    }
};

    createDiv();
    $('#doSer').click(function(){
        alert($('#userQues').serialize())
    })

});
```

Comment: No. I am serializing the "explorer_form" not the "userQues" itself. Because the "userQues" is the div where I append some divs.

Comment: do an e.preventDefault() on your submit button, the data is getting serialized correctly, you just don't see it. Here, I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9v3khbts/1/

Comment: Yes, after testing it in the jsfiddle, it seems to be working. But still I can't find out why in my code, it is not including the data. Maybe I have some errors in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<form id='explorer_form'>
    <input id='uname' name='uname' type='text'/>
    <div id='userQues'></div>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="output"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function createDiv () {
    var count = 5;
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
        $('#userQues').append("<div class='col-md-4'> <div class='form-group'> " + 
            "<label class='control-label' for ='data[" + i + "][questiona]'> Question A </label>" +
              // "<input id='data[" + i + "][questiona]' name='data[" + i + "][questiona]' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/>" +
            "<input id=data["+ i +"][questiona] name=data"+i+" type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/>" +
            "</div> </div>"                   
        );
    }
};
createDiv();

$('#explorer_form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $(".output").text($("#explorer_form").serialize());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine for me.

Don't use [] in ID or name.

Output will be -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use .appendTo() https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/ instead of .append()